# Convert array of objects to object with sub-arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, sub-array

I search around for a bit but found nothing that did exactly what I'm after nor anything that really aided me in acheiveing what I'd like.

I have data in this format from a DB:

```
[
    {
        "datetime": "20170208183021",
        "ping": "11.201858520507812",
        "download": "28129628.324328355",
        "upload": "65169139.37489863"
    },
    {
        "datetime": "20170208181514",
        "ping": "7.826685905456543",
        "download": "300487650.87967044",
        "upload": "128210163.86553746"
    },
    {
        "datetime": "20170208180034",
        "ping": "19.550085067749023",
        "download": "17300126.504837424",
        "upload": "16650978.464359928"
    }
]
```

I'd like to convert it all to this format:

```
{
    "datetime": [
        "20170208183021",
        "20170208181514",
        "20170208180034"
    ],
    "ping": [
        "11.201858520507812",
        "7.826685905456543",
        "19.550085067749023"
    ],
    "download": [
        "28129628.324328355",
        "300487650.87967044",
        "17300126.504837424"
    ],
    "upload": [
        "65169139.37489863",
        "128210163.86553746",
        "16650978.464359928"
    ]
}
```

I'm guessing the best way is to use map but I wasn't sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an working example. You don't need anything fancy, a simple `foreach` will do the trick.

```
$json = <<<EOS
[
    {
        "datetime": "20170208183021",
        "ping": "11.201858520507812",
        "download": "28129628.324328355",
        "upload": "65169139.37489863"
    },
    {
        "datetime": "20170208181514",
        "ping": "7.826685905456543",
        "download": "300487650.87967044",
        "upload": "128210163.86553746"
    },
    {
        "datetime": "20170208180034",
        "ping": "19.550085067749023",
        "download": "17300126.504837424",
        "upload": "16650978.464359928"
    }
]
EOS;

$array = \json_decode($json, true);
$results = [
    'datetime' => [],
    'ping'     => [],
    'download' => [],
    'upload'   => [],
];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $results['datetime'][] = $value['datetime'];
    $results['ping'][]     = $value['ping'];
    $results['download'][] = $value['download'];
    $results['upload'][]   = $value['upload'];
}

$results = \json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $results;
```

Comment: After playing around with what you suggested, I simply go it down to `foreach ($array as $value) { foreach ($value as $key => $val) { $data[$key][] = $val; } }`. PHP seems to create all the parent keys it needs as it goes :)

Comment: Did you comment on the wrong answer???  The code that you just posted that you used came directly from the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's JSON, so assuming you decode it as an array:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

To build it dynamically regardless of how many keys, just loop one to get key names and extract those:

```
foreach($array[0] as $key => $val) {
    $result[$key] = array_column($array, $key);
}
```

A longer way around:

```
foreach($array as $values) {
    foreach($values as $key => $val)
    $result[$key][] = $val;
}
```

It will be an object when encoded:

```
$array = json_encode($result);
```